# How to change the RequestInterface dynamically while parsing limited JSON using Retrofit?

Tags: java, android, json, wordpress, android-recyclerview

I am trying to incorporate the endless recyclerview by populating it with data fetched from a json source. Now, I am using the Wordpress JSON API.

The problem is that, my JSON is very large. Also, instead of loading all the data in the RecyclerView at once, I want the user to scroll down in order to fetch new data.

To get limited JSON, I am appending the &offset=10 tag. But, the problem is that every time the user scrolls down, I need to change the @GET url...

But my Interface looks like this:

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;

public interface RequestInterface {

    @GET("?json=get_posts&include=title,excerpt,content,attachments&offset=10")
    Call<JSONResponse> getJSON();
}
```

So, when I pass the request code from my MainActivity:

```
    public void getFeed() {

        Call<JSONResponse> listCall = mManager.getFlowerService().getAllFlowers();
        listCall.enqueue(new Callback<JSONResponse>() {
            @Override


            public void onResponse(Call<JSONResponse> call, Response<JSONResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccess()) {
                    flowerList =  new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(response.body().getPosts()));
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),flowerList.get(0).getTitle()+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    for (int i = 0; i < flowerList.size(); i++) {
                        ModelClass flower = flowerList.get(i);

                     SaveIntoDatabase task = new SaveIntoDatabase();
                       task.execute(flower);

                        mAdapter.addFlyp(flower);
                    }
                } else {
                    int sc = response.code();
                    switch (sc) {
                        case 400:
                            Log.e("Error 400", "Bad Request");
                            break;
                        case 404:
                            Log.e("Error 404", "Not Found");
                            break;
                        default:
                            Log.e("Error", "Generic Error");
                    }
                }
                mDialog.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JSONResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                mDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }


        });
    }
```

How can I change the offset value by passing an integer to the interface?

Comment: change `getJSON()` to `getJSON(@SomeAnnotation int offset)` then use docs to see what annotation to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the offset value as a parameter to your method:

```
public interface RequestInterface {

    @GET("?json=get_posts&include=title,excerpt,content,attachments")
    Call<JSONResponse> getJSON(@Query("offset") int offset);
}
```

Comment: Thanks... That was it!